# A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-community_datetimepicker'

Tags: react-native

I'm working on react native project I've installed @react-native-community/datetimepicker
by this two commands:

```
npm install @react-native-community/datetimepicker --save
```

And:

```
npx react-native link @react-native-community/datetimepicker
```

while I'm running the app i've found errors , So I've runned ./gradlew clean
I've found this error:

```
PS D:\test 2\Smart Roster\android> ./gradlew clean

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-community_datetimepicker'.
> Could not create service of type ScriptHandlerInternal using ProjectScopeServices.createScriptHandler().
   > Could not create service of type DependencyLockingProvider using DependencyResolutionScopeServices.createDependencyLockingProvider().
      > Illegal char <:> at index 32: D:\test 2\Smart Roster\android\C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\gradle\dependency-locks

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
```

Comment: Which version of RN you are using?

Comment: This is from package.json "react-native": "0.64.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in npmjs, for version >=0.60 for linking just call:

```
npx pod-install
```

Then rebuild your project.

This if you are working on MacOs.

If you are working on Windows, npmjs said:

> Autolinking is not yet implemented on Windows, so Manual installation
> is needed.

So, please follow [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/datetimepicker#windows) to link library on Windows

When guide says `Right-click solution icon in Solution Explorer > Add > Existing Project Select` you should go in `Solution Explorer` tab, right click in `Solution` icon, then select `Add -> Existing Project...`. Look image below:

[image]

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/datetimepicker) the reference.

Comment: I have this error whine I'm runnin npx pod-install :Scanning for pods...
CocoaPods is only supported on darwin machines

Comment: @Mira as explained [here](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues/364#issuecomment-632046596) "CocoaPods are only available for MacOS. You can use Expo, which has dependencies bundled inside, so you can develop iOS on Windows."

Comment: but I'm not working with expo , it's an app with typescript only

Comment: @Mira and infact library said "Autolinking is not yet implemented on Windows, so Manual installation is needed.". So you have to manually link this. [Here](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#windows) the guide.

Comment: Sorry , I'm working with visual studio code  what to do?

Comment: @Mira sorry but I really don't know.